# Need help editing the .DAT files in NexusTK's folder

Tags: technical-issues, nexustk

It's the very first MMO, and so most of it's files are in .dat format. This means I will have to locate the original programs responsible for creating those files. I've searched across the Internet, but have had no luck thus far in finding a program to edit the files (Notepad ++ doesn't even work). Is there a program to edit .dat files?

Comment: Is [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NexusTK) the game you're referring to?

Comment: Yes, its website is www.nexustk.com. Very old, old online game.

Answer (score -2):

Extract the dat file using game extractor like i did, i use some sounds for my game project. The image files in epf format, the tiles image can be open by map editor.

Comment: Where might one find this game extractor?